# openssl_pkey_get_private returning false for one key

Tags: php, openssl, php-openssl

I am having two keys. For one it is working completely fine and giving the response as `resource(368) of type (OpenSSL key)` but for the other key it is just returning a false.

In both the cases I am not providing the path, but instead the string itself.

The key in which **its working** is like this :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEA74waKCtYqw7U7gE93BCn0CPmulFd1K8AaJqqBjOLe//okAuA
<...........................................................>
MGgCk1mrd65nf6JWsxb3RVcQ7jYxyFs3Pr4LFcgn1K0aTLnlwarBFjt+J3Y=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And the key in which **it is not working** is like this :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,14CA8(removing some values)2B6244

LwBvVX6TbdS9XYg0xywoLbhiaYK5UE6SQnATXJ8fXfJit+F4XcOfmWyQn+UsJRnM
<...........................................................>
s8M/Fe7YpkORsGSzQ6f5YslfmbmCsdCFDiBnTaIe45NP8IBULWY/vm45bYFteKUs
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

PS : I have hidden most part of keys for security.

Is there anything about the keys value also that affects the openssl to throw an error?

CODE :

```
$pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private(my_private_key_in_string_form);
```

**EDIT :**

What I on my research could find is that the second key is in an encrypted form whereas the first one is in the raw form.
But I am yet not able to find how to convert this encrypted private key to its raw form from an already created key.

Comment: Can you pls  post the code, to show how you are calling openssl_pkey_get_private function

Comment: @Pras I edited the answer with the code, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the keys, the one which works is not protected with passpharase, the one that you say fails is protected with passpharase, also the call to `openssl_pkey_get_private()` , does not have second optional parameter for passpharese. I am referring the dcumentation from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php

So if your private key is encrypted, you have to specify the passpharase so that the key can be read properly by the `openssl_pkey_get_private()` API